# How to change the color of circle radius on google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I want to put radius circle on google map. I have already checked google maps api docs but still don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
 const MyMapComponent = compose(
          withProps({
            googleMapURL: googleMapsApiKey,
            loadingElement: <div style={mapConfigStyle.loadingElement} />,
            containerElement: <div style={mapConfigStyle.containerElement} />,
            mapElement: <div style={mapConfigStyle.mapElement} />
          }),
          withScriptjs,
          withGoogleMap,
        )(props => (
          <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={12} 
            defaultCenter={{ lat: Number(this.state.latitude), lng: Number(this.state.longitude) }}

          >
         <Circle
          radius={1900}
          fillColor="#2a5777"
          center={{ lat: Number(this.state.latitude), lng: Number(this.state.longitude) }}
        />
            {props.isMarkerShown && (
              <Marker position={{ lat: Number(this.state.latitude), lng: Number(this.state.longitude) }} options={{ icon: { url: '/boost_marker.png' } }} />
            )}
          </GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Are you using the [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) library? If so, you should be able to use the [Circle wrapper](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#!/Circle). Something like this up top: `import { Circle } from "react-google-maps"` and this between `<GoogleMap>` open/close tag => `<Circle radius={5} center={{ lat: Number(this.state.latitude), lng: Number(this.state.longitude) }} />`

Comment: yes i am ,how  can I custom the circle radius? like the color for example @thmsdnnr

Comment: You can set the radius to whatever constant or variable you like. The `options` prop in the react library maps directly to [the google.maps.CircleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#CircleOptions) object, where you can define things like `fillColor`. The docs lay out pretty clearly where and what you can customize. Have a look through them for properties you're interested in customizing and give it a try. If you're still having trouble, update your question with the code you attempted.

Comment: i just updated my question with the code I attempted to change the circle's color ,and the color still not change, can you please show me the right way to put color on it? or you can just edit my code above ,thanks @thmsdnnr

Comment: you're close! But you have to pass your Circle tag an `options` prop, which must be an object instead of a string. It'll look just like the `center=` prop you already have in your Circle tag. Except, in the options prop, you'll set your `fillColor` as a key and the color code as the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Circle
    defaultCenter={{
        lat: mapPosition.lat,
        lng: mapPosition.lng
    }}
    options={{fillColor:"#2a5777"}}                    
    radius={}
/>
```

put fillColor inside options as such

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

```
const options = {
        fillColor: color,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 0.1,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        clickable: false,
        draggable: false,
        editable: false,
        visible: true,
        zIndex: 1
}

<Circle
    key={id}
    radius={1000}
    center={{
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude
    }}
    options={options}
/>
```